# Access select element value on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Refactoring how a select element is written and trying to figure out how to access the value of a select drop-down on form submit.

Currently, the code looks like this:

```
  <select onchange="myFunc(this.value)">Some Options</select>
```

Would like to do something like this:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunc("Send the value of the select element")">
    <select>Some Options</select>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

What's the best way to grab the value of the select element given that "this" has a new context?

Comment: You could try `<form onsubmit="myFunc(this.getElementsByTagName('SELECT')[0])">`

Comment: "given that "this" has a new context" -- Could you please elaborate your question a little bit further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have only one select in form and this refers to form context.Try this:

```
 $(this).find('select').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you prefer a solution with pure JS or can you use JQuery?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myselect').change(function() {
                console.log($(this).val());             
            });
        });
    </script>
    <form id="myform">
        <select id="myselect">
            <option value="val1">opt1</option>
            <option value="val2">opt2</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the alternative with pure Javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="domisready()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var domisready = function() {
            document.getElementById('myselect').onchange = function() {
                console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
            };
        };
    </script>
    <form id="myform">
        <select id="myselect">
            <option value="val1">opt1</option>
            <option value="val2">opt2</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can use jQuery but I was looking to get away from firing the callback function on the change event. I "got it to work" by using `<form onsubmit="myFunc($(this).find('select').val():)">` above. Either way, you provided a nice code example, thanks!